# adding two objects without overriding keys within the objects Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, javascript-objects

i have two objects, a master and a temp
the master looks like

```
{
    "gnome":{
        "child":{
            name:"child",
            race:"gnome"
        },
        "youngling":{
            name:"youngling",
            race:"gnome"
        }
    },
    "human":{...},
    ...
}
```

and the temp looks like

```
{
    "gnome":{
        "man":{
            name:"man",
            race:"gnome"
        }
}
```

what i am trying to do is have the temp be added to the master like

```
{
    "gnome":{
        "child":{...},
        "youngling":{...},
        "man":{...}
    },
    "human":{...},
    ...
}
```

what i currently have

```
let obj = {}
function generateJson() {
        let race = getinput("race").value
        let name = getinput("name").value


        let temp = {}
        temp[`${race}`] = {}
        temp[`${race}`][`${name}`] = {
            name: name,
            race: race
        }

        obj = Object.assign(obj, temp)
}
```

all it does is empties and override the first duplicate key with the temp value
a.e. `{gnome:{man:{..}}}`

earlier this question was closed because it should have been awnsered with [How can I merge properties of two JavaScript objects dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171251/how-can-i-merge-properties-of-two-javascript-objects-dynamically)
which sadly it didn't, all of the solutions override objects within objects, i want to add to similar keys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chris Ferdinandi wrote a helper for this [here](https://vanillajstoolkit.com/helpers/deepassign/);

I've added an updated version below, but wanted to add a fix for my biggest frustration with `Object.assign`.

It mutates the source material. To fix this, you can add an empty object as the first argument of the `deepAssign` function, or use function `copyDeepAssign` below.

```js
// mutates the source material
function deepAssign(...args) {

    // Make sure there are objects to merge
    const len = args.length;
    if (len < 1) return;
    
    const main = args[0];
    if (len < 2) return main

    // Merge all objects into first
    let i = 0,
        curr;
    while (i < len) {
        curr = args[i];
        for (var key in curr) {
            // If it's an object, recursively merge
            // Otherwise, push to key
            if (Object.prototype.toString.call(curr[key]) === '[object Object]') {
                main[key] = deepAssign(main[key] || {}, curr[key]);
            } else {
                main[key] = curr[key];
            }
        }
        i++;
    }

    return main;
}

// Doesn't mutate the source material
function copyDeepAssign(...args) {
    const base = {};
    
    return deepAssign(base, ...args);
}
```

Comment: thank you, this works bit large but sometimes thats what we need!

Comment: @Odinh Depending on your tolerance for code-golfing, you can use the same helper but only 170 characters: `let dA=(e,...g)=>{let o,r,a=g.length,m=0;if(a<1)return e;for(;m<a;)for(r in o=g[m++])"[object Object]"=={}.toString.call(o[r])?e[r]=dA(e[r]||{},o[r]):e[r]=o[r];return e};` You can see it expaned in this [CodePen](https://codepen.io/frankie_tech/pen/XWNGELX) with working proof :)

Answer (score 2):

Based on your example, this should work

```
<script>
function merge_without_override(master, temp) {
    for(var key in temp) {
    if( !temp.hasOwnProperty(key) )
        continue;
    if(master[key] !== undefined) // key already exists in master.
        continue; 

        master[key] = Object.assign(temp[key]); // key doesnt exist, assign it.
  }
}

var master = {
    "gnome":{
        "child":{
            name:"child",
            race:"gnome"
        },
        "youngling":{
            name:"youngling",
            race:"gnome"
        }
    },
    "human":{}
};
var temp = {
    "gnome":{
        "man":{
            name:"man",
            race:"gnome"
        }
    }
};
console.log("master before merge");
console.log(master);
merge_without_override(master["gnome"], temp["gnome"]);
console.log("master after merge");
console.log(master);

</script>
```

Output (in jsfiddle):

```
{
  gnome: {
    child: { ... },
    man: { ... },
    youngling: { ... }
  },
  human: { ... }
}
```

JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/h10fpcx2/

Comment: this is a decently small function! and would have loved if this worked, the issue here is that if the top key does not exist it does not add anything, a.e master = {}

thanks though!